# show that the height of the cylinder of maximum volume that can be inscribed within a cone of height $h$ is $\frac{h}3$.

Tags: derivatives, maxima-minima

show that the height of the cylinder of maximum volume that can be inscribed within a cone of height $h$ is $\frac{h}3$.

I have tried solving this sum but am unable to substitute the radius of the cylinder in terms of $h$.

Comment: See [this](https://www.sccollege.edu/Departments/Mathematics/Documents/Math%20180/04-07-032_Optimization_Problems.pdf) for finding the maximum volume of a cylinder in a cone of height $h$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

[image]

Look at the figure. With:
$$
BH=h \quad HC=R \quad FG=x \quad HG=r
$$

from the similarity of the triangles $BHC$ and $FGC$ we have:

$$
h:x=R:(R-r)
$$
so that $r=\frac{R}{h}(h-x)$

Now you can express the volume of the cylinder as $V=\pi r^2x=\pi \frac{R^2}{h^2}(h-x)^2x $.

Maximize this function.